# Store Data in Encrypted format in java files?

Tags: java

How to store data in Encrypted format or binary format in any file?? in  File Handling using JAVA.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  This is not "write my code for me.com".  Also, your question is vague and difficult to answer.  Please add information so we know what data you're trying to encrypt and what you think you're going to do with this "encrypted" data.

Comment: Actually I have one Java Form where in that one field is password field. And i am storing that entry in prop.property file for further use. In that ,password field  is in plane text format i want to make it in nonreadable format or encrypted format how to do that??

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you encrypt the file using Keyczar,

http://code.google.com/p/keyczar/

keyczar takes care of the details of ciphers and key management and it's also platform independent. You can encrypt in Java and decrypt in other languages.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you try out first [Jasypt](http://www.jasypt.org/) to encrypt and decrypt strings or binaries, etc. But it really depends on the requirements.